# Nested loop to dynamically create objects

Tags: javascript, loops

I am trying to create a loop or a nested loop that will create one(1) array containing many objects:

```
// example of the object structure
obj0.country = distAttr[0];
obj0[municipo[0]] = econ[0];
obj0[municipo[1]] = edu[0];
obj0[municipo[2]] = gov[0];
obj0[municipo[3]] = health[0];
obj0[municipo[4]] = infra[0];
obj0[municipo[5]] = social[0];

obj1.country = distAttr[1];
obj1[municipo[0]] = econ[1];
obj1[municipo[1]] = edu[1];
obj1[municipo[2]] = gov[1];
obj1[municipo[3]] = health[1];
obj1[municipo[4]] = infra[1];
obj1[municipo[5]] = social[1];

// ... obj18
```

This is what i have so far:

```
// create all the objects, distAttr length is 19
for (var i = 0; i < distAttr.length; i++) {
    window['obj'+i ] = {};
};

// distName length is 6
var number = distName.length;

// this loop I can't figure out
for (var j = 0; i < distName.length; j++) {
    window['obj'+i ][municipo[j]] = econ[i];
};

// bind the objects to the array
for (var i = 0; i < distAttr.length; i++) {
    chartArray[i] = window['obj'+i];
};
```

Comment: But what's the problem you're facing?

Comment: I don't see a nested loop here.

Comment: I can not figure out how to build multiple objects that have the same structure as the above example. window['obj'+i ][municipo[j]] = econ[i]; does not create the objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the object within a single loop:

```
// Set up some variables and the field values you will use:
var j,
    obj,
    ec = municipo[0],
    ed = municipo[1],
    go = municipo[2],
    he = municipo[3],
    in = municipo[4],
    so = municipo[5];

// Loop through the array.
for (i = 0; i < distAttr.length; i++) {
    // Create an object with a country field. 
    obj = { country: distAttr[i] };
    // Populate the other fields.
    obj[ec] = econ[i];
    obj[ed] = edu[i];
    obj[go] = gov[i];
    obj[he] = health[i];
    obj[in] = infra[i];
    obj[so] = social[i];
    // Set the array index to contain the object
    // (and if you need it then create a global object `objx`
    //  - not sure if you need it though.)
    chartArray[i] = window['obj'+i] = obj;
};
```

Comment: `obj` will reference a new object at each iteration but at the end of the iteration `obj` is assigned to be an element of `chartArray` so the references maintained in that array are not lost or overwritten. You are going to end up with an array of multiple different objects (rather than overwriting the object multiple times).

Comment: The reason that `obj` is declared as a variable outside the scope of the loop is so that JavaScript does not try to create a new variable (and allocate new memory) with each iteration.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think the engine create a new variable, but kills the old one.

Comment: It will create an `{}` object with each iteration but does not need to re-create `obj` (as a reference to the `{}`) with each iteration and does not need to garbage collect `obj` (as it will be re-used for subsequent iterations). If you declare `var obj` inside the loop then it may need to create both with each iteration and may also need to garbage collect the `obj` reference for each iteration (depending on how it can optimize the block).